# design pattern selection for workers

Tags: design-patterns

main goal is to use maximum number of design patterns :)

exist some **entrypoint** worker script which accept 2 params

1) "start" or "check" if working

2) worker name

```
#entrypoint start HelloWorld
#entrypoint check HelloWorld
```

script can check if worker running in different ways so for this part i could use Strategy pattern

workers can do different jobs, so for this part i could use Factory Method

what kind of pattern could be used to select which action should be used "start" or "check"

what other patterns you could imagine for such a task

Comment: Imagine that you hired a painter to paint your house, and he told you that his goal was to use as many colors as possible.

Comment: For "start" or "check" [command design pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-command-pattern) could be useful. For different "check" behaviors [strategy design pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/java-strategy-pattern). While Factory Method I think is a good approach if the objective is to use multiple design patterns I would use [abstract factory](https://www.baeldung.com/java-abstract-factory-pattern) and [signleton](https://www.baeldung.com/java-singleton) design patterns

Comment: thank you Valentin, when was thinking about the commands missed the command pattern itself :)

Comment: Matt, a bit different situation here. I'm the painter and my goal is to practice in paining. i can use different tools which may help me to paint, so im asking for help more experienced painters about which tools should be used to paint this house. If you can advice me a place with the quiz for example where i can think about the different tasks and practice in design patterns choice i would appreciate it